# Почему то не работает функция из примера известной книги https://codernet.ru/books/go/programmirovanie_na_go_mark_sammerfild/

Tags: функции, golang

https://play.golang.org/p/iH9AF4BnTon

Вот этот текст, которую система считает ошибочной на 218 странице:

```
type Point struct{ x, y, z int }
func (point Point) String() string {
    return Sprintf("(%d,%d,%d)", point.x, point.y, point.z)
}
```

Comment: А не надо внутри функции объявлять методы. Вот как надо: https://play.golang.org/p/rxMUJRVbB8-

Comment: Спасибо )   Действительно глупый вопрос.   Пришел удалять, когда понял где стормозил, но Вы меня опередили. Придется оставить )